# String split in python for ldap return values

Tags: python, python-3.x

My LDAP Returns values as below

```
[('CN=b12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com', {'Fname': [Jose, Movi'], 'location': [b'London'], 'mail': [b'jose.movi@google.com'], 'title': [b'Sales -Exec -Retail']})]
[('CN=h12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com', {'Fname': [Lorraine, Moses'], 'location': [b'Boston'], 'mail': [b'Lorraine.Moses@google.com'], 'title': [b'Sales -ExecIII -Retail']})]
[('CN=o12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com', {'Fname': [Andy, Cameron'], 'location': [b'NewYork'], 'mail': [b'Andy.Cameron@google.com'], 'title': [b'Customer Support II - Fixed']})]
```

I would like to split them as below for each entry and print them as below

```
DisplayName:Jose, Movi
Location:London
Email:jose.movi@google.com
Designation:Sales -Exec -Retail
```

Apologize to me in advance as I'm a beginner in python.

Comment: Those strings (I assume that's what they are) do not represent valid Python or JSON structures. You'll probably need to modify them before you can actually use them

Comment: Are you wanting them saved as a dictionary, then printed?

Comment: Is `Fname` `[Jose, Movi']` or `['Jose, Movi']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Individual lists

When you define `x` as:

```
x = [('CN=b12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
      {'Fname': ['Jose, Movi'],
       'location': [b'London'],
       'mail': [b'jose.movi@google.com'],
       'title': [b'Sales -Exec -Retail']})]
```

You can print in a `key` `value` manner:

```
for k, v in x[0][1].items():
    try:
        print(f"{k.title()}: {', '.join(a.decode('utf-8') for a in v)}")
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, AttributeError):
        # If you try to decode a regular string
        print(f"{k.title()}: {', '.join(v)}")
```

Outputs

```
Fname: Jose, Movi
Location: London
Mail: jose.movi@google.com
Title: Sales -Exec -Retail
```

---

Or assign custom values for each `key`:

```
def printer(k, v):
    try:
        print(f"{k.title()}: {', '.join(a.decode('utf-8') for a in v)}")
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, AttributeError):
        # If you try to decode a regular string
        print(f"{k.title()}: {', '.join(v)}")


for k, v in x[0][1].items():
    if k == "Fname":
        printer("DisplayName", v)
    elif k == "mail":
        printer("Email", v)
    elif k == "title":
        printer("Designation", v)
    else:
        printer(k, v)
```

Outputs:

```
Displayname: Jose, Movi
Location: London
Email: jose.movi@google.com
Designation: Sales -Exec -Retail
```

If you are using `>= Python3.10` you can use `match` statements for the custom titles:

```
for k, v in x[0][1].items():
    match k:
        case "Fname":
            printer("DisplayName", v)
        case "mail":
            printer("Email", v)
        case "title":
            printer("Designation", v)
        case _:
            # Default case
            printer(k, v)
```

#### All lists

When you define `x` as:

```
x = [[('CN=b12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
       {'Fname': ['Jose, Movi'],
        'location': [b'London'],
        'mail': [b'jose.movi@google.com'],
        'title': [b'Sales -Exec -Retail']})],
     [('CN=h12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
      {'Fname': ['Lorraine, Moses'],
       'location': [b'Boston'],
       'mail': [b'Lorraine.Moses@google.com'],
       'title': [b'Sales -ExecIII -Retail']})],
     [('CN=o12345,OU=Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
      {'Fname': ['Andy, Cameron'],
       'location': [b'NewYork'],
       'mail': [b'Andy.Cameron@google.com'],
       'title': [b'Customer Support II - Fixed']})]]
```

You can edit your examples to be in another `for` loop for `i`:

```
for i in x:
    for k, v in i[0][1].items():
    # Rest of method goes here
```

---

If you are strictly working with single element lists, you can change `', '.join(a.decode('utf-8') for a in v)` to `v.decode('utf-8')`. And `', '.join(v)` to `v`

Comment: How do you propose converting the OP's data into dictionaries?

Comment: No worries, would you like them saved as dictionaries? @LancelotduLac raised a good point I did not consider

Comment: You have edited the OP's data to make it work with your code. The data, as shown in the OP's question, does not represent any valid Python/JSON structure. A regular expression (as proposed by @GregoirePelegrin) is probably the way to go with this

Comment: @LancelotduLac, all i did was add 3 `'` characters to the first element of `Fname` as I assumed them to be key typos. If the OP finds GregoirePelegrin's more acceptable that's perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

While [@Freddy Mcloughlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14141223/freddy-mcloughlan)'s answer is good when you have dictionaries, the following might be useful if the data comes from a file. Additionally, it makes use of regex, which is always a good exercise.

```py
import re

file = open("test.file", "r", encoding="utf-8")

entry = file.readline()
while entry not in ["", " "]:
    parsing = re.search(r"\'Fname\': \[([^\]]*)\], \'location\': \[b\'([^\]]*)\'\], \'mail\': \[b\'([^\]]*)\'\], \'title\': \[b\'([^\]]*)\'\]", entry)
    name = parsing.group(1)
    location = parsing.group(2)
    mail = parsing.group(3)
    designation = parsing.group(4)
    print(name, location, mail, designation)
    entry = file.readline()

file.close()
```